# IQueryable or List if many requests to a query

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

There are two options for getting items.
I know that IQueryable has lazy loading, and `List` (`.ToList()`) is executed immediately.
Will request `items.FirstOrDefault()` make a request to the database every time you pass the loop or only at the first iteration?
Or should I still convert to `List`?

```
var items = _someDbContext.Items.Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonth(-3);//IQueryable<Items> result
var items = _someDbContext.Items.Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonth(-3).ToList();//List<Items> result
foreach (var oneData in someData)
{
    var searchedItems = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeField == oneData.SomeField);
    //...some code...
}
```

Comment: "Will request items.FirstOrDefault() make a request to the database every time you pass the loop or only at the first iteration?" > every single time. You are executing a different query anyway. Which is faster/better for your case, you only can test

Comment: For debugging I always use ToList() where I can easily hover over the variables and see results.  Late for speed improvements I remove the unecessary ToList().  If you declare a varaible List<object> then you must use ToList() in the query.

Comment: Whynot use .Contains( ?

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will request items.FirstOrDefault() make a request to the database every time you pass the loop

If items is still an `IQueryable`, this will send a query to the database on each iteration through the loop.

If items is a `List<T>`, then you've already retrieved all the results from the database into memory.  Thus calling `FirstOrDefault` in the loop will just be searching within that in-memory collection.

Which one is more efficient will depend on a lot of factors.  Looping through and issuing a bunch of queries is generally called a "chatty API" and is frowned upon.  If you can take the hit once and get all the data in memory, then filter there, you might be better off than incurring all of those round trips to the database.

Of course, if the resultset is *huge*, this might be overwhelm your application's memory.  It might also be bad on the database side, if it's having to scan a huge portion of some table.

A better approach would be if you can push that other search condition into the query.  It seems like this would work:

```
var listOfSomeField = someData.Select(x => x.SomeField).ToList();

var items = _someDbContext.Items
    .Where(x => 
        x.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonth(-3)
        && listOfSomeField.Contains(x.SomeField))
    .ToList();
```